# Has anyone developed a mobile chat application? If so what technologies used?

Tags: angularjs, mobile, chat

Hi I am thinking of developing a chat application preferably using angularjs2 just for fun (My intention is to learn a little bit of angularjs & mobile app building)
If I want to write a simplest chat application what technologies I should use and any resources? 
much appreciate your help. 
thanks
Gopi

Answer (score 0):

Your will need use comet server for delivered message from server to other clients.

For example you can use [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181698/Creating-a-simple-chat-using-CppComet) about using [CppComet](https://github.com/CppComet/comet-server) with php.

CppComet will install persistent connections via websockets with javascript. And you can send requests to CppComet using api from the php or other backend languages when you need to send any message to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Technologies used to develop a mobile chat application:

Server : Ejabberd 
Language : Erlang 
Protocol : XMPP 
Database management : Mnesia & Mysql 
Multimedia files storage : YAWS 
Operating system : FreeBSD

Answer (score 0):

I think **Firebase** ( https://firebase.google.com/ ) is a best option to make chat application.

It's google powered so you have full support. They also provides notifications, live databases service maps and so much more.

If you are willing to learn core architecture see how actually Chat works you can try Socket.io ( https://socket.io/ ). It is used as core library for many chat applications.